# html overlayed ul-li element does not scrolled on android browser

Tags: html, scroll, overlay

This is my html structure.
[image]

section 1 can be scrolled horizontally with li elements
and section 2 can be scrolled vertically.

Before scrolling section2, the section1's scrolling works well.

But, after scrolling section2, and make it like below,
[image]
section 1 does not move and all scrolling event goes to section2.
I can't understand why it works like that. (section1's z-index bigger than section2 so always it is on the section2)

the strange thing is it works well at chrome browser on pc.
but on my android browser(HTC evo), the section1 scrolling doesn't work when section2 scrolled to under section1.

Is there anybody explain this?

thanks for reading.

Comment: I found the section1's control area moved as scrolled. but the visual element fixed. but I don't understand why the control area scrolled too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding "position: absolute;" on section2. so it can move independently.

Because section2's moving is not affected to section1, the section1's control area did not move.

:)